# Displaying sum of field in cluster symbology using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, clustering

Using QGIS, I have a point layer of wind turbines. One of the fields is MW (megawatts produced by the turbine).

I want to display the turbines by clustering. But I to show the sum of MW in the cluster rather than the @cluster_size default.

Comment: WTG produce MWh. MW is the potential output of the turbine. Just to be annoyingly correct. How did you cluster your WTG? Which attributes are preserved during clustering? How large is your data set (aka, could you work manually, or should it be automatically)?

Comment: I am showing the potential MW. Getting the actual MWh is hard enough.

I am using point cluster symbology with single symbol. I may later look at graduating the size of the cluster. if that makes sense.

Comment: Also the shp contains 2180 points and files size is about 17mb

Comment: So you didn't create real clusters, but simply changed the symbology. Please edit your question so it contains this information, thank you. You most likely wont get actual production, since companies tend to keep a tight lid on this data - sorry.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/317107