# QGIS: Symbol size behaving like a Heatmap

Tags: qgis, symbology

I'm using QGIS. I'd like to change the size of my symbols according to a specific numeric value but, unlike the "Graduated" symbol, merging the same near-by value.

For example: in the same area I've got 3 points (almost overlapping), one with a "quantity" value of 2, the others 3. So the merged "quantity" value would be (2+3+3) 8.
I'd like the symbol size to change according to this calculated value.

Comment: The term you are looking for is clustering

Comment: Does https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/363561/qgis-3-10-point-cluster-symbology-sum-attribute answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend saving a copy of your points layer, because `overlay_nearest` is buggy when used on the current layer.

Then you can use this expression (on the layer `points2`) to sum the values of the points (in layer `points1`) within a search radius (1000 m in my case)

```
array_sum(
    overlay_nearest(
        layer:='points1',      -- the original points layer
        expression:=value,     -- the field you want to sum
        limit:=-1,             -- limit -1 returns all available features 
        max_distance:=1000)    -- search radius
    )
```

I called the field `weighted_value` and set the symbol size to this field.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, perfect!