# Clustering points showing the sum of HHS - QGIS 3.18

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, clustering

I have a points layer in QGIS.

Each points represent a building.
In the attribute table, each point has a field representing the number of HHs in the building (1 HH, 2 HHs, etc...)

I want to use the point cluster render in the layer properties to display the sum of the HHs so that when I zoom in or zoom out I can know the total number of HHs (that represent of course several points/buildings on the map).

I found a similar question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317107/clustering-points-and-summing-up-attributes-per-cluster-in-qgis) but it is not what I am looking for exactly.

Comment: So, are you asking how to base the text marker in the cluster symbol on an attribute, or how to base a heat map on an attribute, or how to add a textlabel containing said summed up attribute?

Comment: True, basically, a text marker in the cluster symbol on an attribute. So instead of obtaining  a cluster symbol labeled 2 (since it has 2 points), I will obtain a symbol label 8 for example ( 2 points and each point has 4 HHs)

Comment: You somehow would need to grab the ID of your cluster, in order to use `sum(HH,group_by:=Cluster ID)` succesfully - but I have no ID, if/how you can grab that ID.

Comment: The problem is that I have no ID for now. The idea is that we need to group several points that have 300 HHs in total (we have to draw a border around those points in another layer). And for each group of points/segment, we will give it an unique ID. That's why I needed the sum of HHs to be displayed on the layer as text/label in order to get an idea on how should we group those points

Answer (score 2):

You can imitate the clustering using buffers. [Buffer](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/de/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/vectorgeoprocessing.html#buffer-vectors) your points (be sure to check the dissolve checkbox), create [single-part](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/de/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#multipart-to-singleparts) geometries. Then get the sum of the`HH` values of all points inside the buffer.

On the buffer-layer, use this expression with field calculator ([array_sum](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog318/index.html#feature-support-for-min-max-majority-sum-mean-and-median-functions-on-numerical-arrays) requires QGIS 3.18 or higher):

```
array_sum (overlay_contains( 'points', "HH"))
```

*Points (blue, with `HH` value) and buffers, labeled with the the sum of the HH-value of all points inside it:*
[image]

Comment: I created the buffers and dissolve them
https://imgur.com/8U90xVR
But what do you mean by 'create single-part geometries.'
Also, on the buffer layer, when to input the array_sum formula? in the label properties?

Comment: dissolved buffers are just one single multi-part geometry. Use `Menu Vector / Geometry Tools / Multipart to singleparts`.  The `array_sum ()` expression can be either used to create a new attribute using field calculator or directly as label source.

Comment: array_sum (overlay_contains( 'points', "HH"))
The 'points" is the original layer with points and HH is the attribute?

Comment: yes, that's correct. "HH" is the name of the attribute in the layer 'points'. The expression has to be applied on the buffer layer (dissolved, singlepart)

Comment: Ok, but I think I am doing something wrong because i am obtaining zeros https://imgur.com/b0A1vDT

Comment: Sorry, from this image I cant see what you're doing. Can you share your project with data? Did you apply the expression on the layer with singlepart geometries? Can you select only one of the buffers? You have very long names for your layers, this could create a problem

Comment: Sure https://we.tl/t-ASREZXackd  The HHs attributes in the "points" layer is not totally filled since I am using it an example

Comment: Sorry: as long as HH is empty: how should the sum be something else than 0? Where it is not 0, I get a sum > 0, see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSVQL.jpg

Comment: Oops. That what happens when you are working at 1 am!! stupidity at its best! Thanks!